# Time minus time in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I like to substract time in javascript. I tried various methods, but none of them works.

For example:

```
var endtime = "22:30" // time-range 00 to 24 hours
var time_difference = "2:30" // time to substract from endtime
// wanted result: starttime = "20:00" // time
```

How can i fix this with javascript?

Comment: Use a Date() object.

Comment: @oneway definitely not a duplicate: time != date.

Comment: @Guido Lemmens 2: just convert those time strings into number of seconds and subtract.

Comment: @zerkms : thanks, i converted the time strings into numbers of seconds en substracted them... that did the trick easy!

Answer (score 0):

Using `moment.js`:

```
var endtime = moment({hour: 22, minute: 30});
endtime.subtract(2, 'hours');
endtime.subtract(30, 'minutes');
var result = endtime.format('H:mm');
```

Comment: Nice one down voter! You are so `1337`.

Comment: Was not a downvoter, but your solution may produce wrong results when it's time saving day. It's generally a terrible (or even stupid?) idea to treat time as a date.

Comment: @zerkms You can basically base it on a date + timezone in the past that you are sure has nothing to do with timesaving days/leap years/leap seconds.

Comment: You can, until you do that - your solution may produce incorrect results (and  your answer is still incorrect due to that).

Answer (score 0):

Try using moment.js moment().subtract() method...

http://momentjs.com